# How can I build an application using only a Swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have a basic understanding of how to make iOS apps with Swift in Xcode Projects (I can make apps like flappy birds and an adapted variation of pong). My main target for this year is to be able to at least apply for the [Apple WWDC student scholarship](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/scholarships/). I have read online that the scholarship submission needs to be completed and uploaded in Swift playgrounds.

As I am self-taught, I have little to no experience with Swift playgrounds. So my main question is: how do I make an application in playgrounds? I am used to beginning with a main.storyboard, but I can't find that in Swift playgrounds.

How do you go about creating an interactive application in Swift playgrounds?

Comment: AFAIK you don't make apps using Playgrounds, it's simply a sandbox for you to test a bit of code and see the results straight away. Where did you get this info about the scholarship?

Comment: @GuyKogus https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/scholarships/ it says in the requirement section from last years site, i expect it to be the same this year as it was the same two years ago also.

Comment: One comment I'll make is that how you present yourself in your scholarship submission matters. As an example, take a look at the edits I made to clarify your question, and make sure that you take the time to provide an easy-to-read submission. Even better, have someone you trust make an editing pass over your wording before submitting.

Comment: @BradLarson okay I will definitely take that into consideration, I'm 15 and not the best at english, so i think having an adult read over my written submission would help. Thank you for taking the time to edit my query also, this is my first time actually asking questions on Stack Overflow and so far I am pleasantly surprised with the community. Thanks again.

Comment: @RossMcLaren - We've had several students win WWDC scholarships at a school that I advise, and all of them had a teacher or others proofread their submissions. They get a lot of applications, and the better you can tell your story, the more likely it is they won't overlook yours. Also, creativity matters, so don't limit yourself to traditional application designs. There are many ways to create interactive experiences in a playground that go beyond standard application design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use storyboards directly in a playground, which is why Xcode doesn't support creating a storyboard inside of a playground.  You can access a framework from a storyboard inside of a workspace (including cocoapods), so one solution is to make a framework to load your storyboards.  This doesn't seem to fit with your criteria of making everything in playgrounds though.  So you can either make all of your view programmatically or you can drag in compiled nib files to your Playground Resources folder and load the nibs from there (the playground cannot load xib, which is the XML representation of the nib).